# ViewPager данные исчезают

Tags: android, android-viewpager

У меня есть ViewPager в нем находится фрагменты. Во фрагменте есть RecyclerView, у которого прописано событие для перехода на новый фрагмент. Все правильно переходит, но при нажатие назад, фрагмент становиться пустой, и отрисовывает данные только после перелистывание.

```
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public
        void onClick(final View view) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
            Fragment_texnika_adapter fragment_texnika_adapter = new Fragment_texnika_adapter();
            fragmentTransaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment_texnika_adapter);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable("statictika", model.getTexnika_sobr());
            fragment_texnika_adapter.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            mListener.onContentItemClicked(model);
```

Сам ViewPager

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private Map<Integer, String> mFragmentTags;
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;
private static int NUM_ITEMS = 4;

public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    mFragmentTags = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    this.fragmentActivity = fragmentActivity;
}


// Returns total number of pages
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NUM_ITEMS;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Сводка";
        case 1:
            return "Награды";
        case 2:
            return "Статистика";
        case 3:
            return "Техника";
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return Fragment_cvodka.newInstance();
        case 1:
            return Fragment_dostizenie.newInstance();
           // return Fragment_cvodka.newInstance();
        case 2:
            return Fragment_statistika.newInstance();
        case 3:
            return Fragment_texnika.newInstance();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Object object = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    if (object instanceof Fragment) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;
        String tag = fragment.getTag();
        mFragmentTags.put(position, tag);
    }
    return object;
}


public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String tag = mFragmentTags.get(position);
    if (tag != null) {
        fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewPager не перерисовывает элементы (не перепоказывает, если можно так сказать), поскольку не знает, что у нас используются фрагменты.
Из вариантов решений:

- Завести самостоятельный список фрагментов и в методах разрушения/создания активити/чего-то, где view pager принудительно перерисовывать
- Принудительно разрушать `ViewPager` (я делал `sliderView = null`), а при восстановлении активити/чего ещё переинициализировать `ViewPager`